# How do i receive audio attachment sent by user to Bot?

Tags: python, json, botframework, attachment, azure-bot-service

I have added a step in Waterfall to get attachment from the user.
When testing with BotFramework Emulator i am able to send audio file to the bot and echo back the same file again to the User.Below are the waterfall steps and the code

```
self.add_dialog(
        WaterfallDialog(
            WaterfallDialog.__name__,
            [
                self.project_step,
                self.name_step,
                self.description_step,
                **self.attachment_step**,
                self.confirm_step,
                self.final_step,
            ],
        )
    )
```

Below is the code for attachment step:

```
async def attachment_step(self, step_context: WaterfallStepContext) -> DialogTurnResult:
    confluence_details = step_context.options

    # Capture the results of the previous step
    confluence_details.description = step_context.result
    message_text = "please add an attachment"
    prompt_options = PromptOptions(
        prompt=MessageFactory.text(
            "add an attachment"
        ),
        retry_prompt=MessageFactory.text(
            "The attachment must be a mp4/wav audio file."
        ),
    )


    return await step_context.prompt(AttachmentPrompt.__name__, prompt_options)





async def confirm_step(
    self, step_context: WaterfallStepContext
) -> DialogTurnResult:

    confluence_details = step_context.options

    confluence_details.audioFile = (
        None if not step_context.result else step_context.result[0]
    )
    if confluence_details.audioFile:
            await step_context.context.send_activity(
                MessageFactory.attachment(
                    confluence_details.audioFile, "This is your audio file."
                )
            )

@staticmethod
async def file_prompt_validator(prompt_context: PromptValidatorContext) -> bool:
    if not prompt_context.recognized.succeeded:
        await prompt_context.context.send_activity(
            "No attachments received. Proceeding without attachment..."
        )

        # We can return true from a validator function even if recognized.succeeded is false.
        return True

    attachments = prompt_context.recognized.value

    valid_file = [
        attachment
        for attachment in attachments
        if attachment.content_type in ["audio/mp3", "audio/mp4","audio/wav"]
    ]

    prompt_context.recognized.value = valid_file

    # If none of the attachments are valid images, the retry prompt should be sent.
    return len(valid_file) > 0
```

The code works fine in emulator .

What i don't get is how do i send an audio file from User Application to bot?
Can i send Audio file as base64 encoded string.If yes,what changes do i need to make at Bot's end.

I could find everywhere that file is to be sent in content URL that contains the URL of the location where file is hosted.
I am unable to receive the file sent from the User Application to bot.

I am attaching a screenshot of conversation flow for reference.
[image: converstaion flow]

[image]

**Edit**:- The previous issue was resolved. I was able to receive Audio file as Base64 encoded string.The issue was with the JSON being sent.In contentUrl it is supposed to be an array of attachments.My bad

**Edit1**:- When trying to send an audio file as base64 encoded string, It gives error for some file as:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "MessageSizeTooBig",
        "message": "Activity body too large for storage. Try using attachments to reduce the activity size."
    }
}
```

What does this actually mean?

As i could see from this [link](https://github.com/microsoft/botframework-sdk/issues/5302) there is an upper limit on activity size.
Could someone please suggest the most feasible way to send audio files to bot?

Comment: If your issue was resolved, would you like to post that resolution as an answer?

Comment: @KyleDelaney I have posted the answer. Maybe you could provide some insights on the same.

Comment: Are you using a custom Direct Line iOS client like in your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61635984/can-a-user-send-attachment-along-with-message-on-text-prompt-in-a-waterfall-step

Comment: @KyleDelaney Yes, we are using custom Direct Line iOS client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an error that says "message size too big," it means what it says. When it suggests that you use attachments, it means attachments that link to remote HTTP/HTTPS locations rather than embedding data. You should try uploading the uploading the file or using a service that's geared towards transferring audio like the [Direct Line Speech channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directlinespeech).