# Can a user send attachment along-with message on Text prompt in a waterfall step?

Tags: python, json, botframework, attachment, azure-bot-service

Lets say we have following steps in our waterfall dialog:

```
self.add_dialog(TextPrompt(TextPrompt.__name__))
    self.add_dialog(
        WaterfallDialog(
            WaterfallDialog.__name__,
            [
                self.project_step,
                self.name_step,
                self.confirm_step,
                self.final_step,
            ],
        )
    )

async def project_step(
    self, step_context: WaterfallStepContext
) -> DialogTurnResult:
    """
    If a project name has not been provided, prompt for one.
    :param step_context:
    :return DialogTurnResult:
    """
    confluence_details = step_context.options

    if confluence_details.project is None:
        message_text = key.query_project_confluence_text.value + "?"
        prompt_message = MessageFactory.text(
            message_text, message_text, InputHints.expecting_input
        )
        return await step_context.prompt(
            TextPrompt.__name__, PromptOptions(prompt=prompt_message)
        )
    return await step_context.next(confluence_details.project)
```

If a user send an attachment along-with text to the bot at the prompt.
Is it possible to get both in **step_context.result**.

In **on_message_activity** i could check using **TurnContext.activity.attachments** for attachment but how do i receive the same using Waterfall step_context and the Text message as well in subsequent step?

Request body will be as below:

```
{
    "text":"Hello there",
    "type":"message",
    "from":{
        "id":"xyz"
    },
    "attachments":{
        "contentType":"audio/wav",
        "name":"BabyElephantWalk60.wav",
        "contentUrl":"data:audio/wav;base64,UklGRvAEAgBXQVZFZm10IBAA
    }
}
```

Client side i.e iOS App will be using directline Api 
**https://directline.botframework.com/v3/directline/conversations/EdWGs8IdmjNIy5j2E93EHW-a/activities** to send the Activity.

iOS application is using speech kit.

On prompt, Whatever user speaks,the message along with audio file of it is to be sent to bot over directline in the request body as provided above.And,this will be done using mic button.

Is it possible to do so?

Comment: I don't know of any channels that allow a user to send text and an attachment in the same message. What channel are you using?

Comment: @KyleDelaney We are using DirectLine Channel. So,In order to get attachment, Attachment Prompt is the only way?I am new to BotFramework, I don't have much idea.

Comment: Attachment prompts, like all prompts, are dialogs. Prompts help you handle user input, but they aren't "the only way" to do so. Your bot would still receive anything the user sends to it even if it didn't have any dialogs or even state. The question of dialogs is entirely separate. I need to know how you intend on getting both an attachment and text from the user. Are you using Web Chat? Do you want to build a special client that can send an attachment and text in the same activity, or would you be satisfied by having the user send them on separate turns?

Comment: Yes,we are using web chat and according to our usecase , Client side code is supposed  to send text and the audio output of the same text together. To be specific, User won't be attaching the audio file, It will be the client side code that does this part.@KyleDelaney

Comment: Your question says the user request will contain a JPEG attachment. If that's not the case, would you like to edit your question to explain that you're actually trying to send an audio attachment? Also, please provide repro steps to show how you're sending text with an audio attachment. For example, are you using the attachment upload button or the microphone button? And are you using Cognitive Services Speech?

Comment: I have updated the question.Maybe it could provide a bit more clarity on what we are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for the information, but now you're saying your Direct Line client is an iOS app. Does this mean you're not using Web Chat? When you say Speech Kit do you mean the [Apple Speech Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/speech)? Have you considered using Direct Line Speech? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/direct-line-speech

Comment: @KyleDelaney Sorry for the misinformation. As of now we have only iOS app as our Direct Line client. And yes It's Apple Speech Framework.We didn't try using Direct Line Speech. Maybe we will consider using it in next phase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be treating this like a bot question when really it's more of a client question. Your bot can only respond to the activities it receives, so there won't be any way for your bot to handle an activity with both audio and text if the client never sends an activity with both audio and text. Since you're using your own Direct Line client, it's up to you to allow your client to send such an activity. Since audio files are normally very large, I recommend uploading the file rather than putting a data URL in the attachment.

Ordinarily, the user would send an attachment and text as separate activities on separate turns. The bot would handle the data on those separate turns by keeping track of a dialog in its state, and it would probably be a waterfall dialog. It sounds like you don't want to do this because the text and the attachment are really the same data in your case.

On the bot side, you can access the text and attachments of the activity outside of any dialog if you like. You also have direct access to the activity inside a waterfall step following any prompt, because the step context contains the turn context which contains the activity.

```
text = step_context.context.activity.text
attachments = step_context.context.activity.attachments
```

You can do this with a text prompt or an attachment prompt. If you want to be able to access those things in `step_context.result`, you could make your own prompt that puts the whole activity in the result. You can use [`ActivityPrompt`](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-python/blob/master/libraries/botbuilder-dialogs/botbuilder/dialogs/prompts/activity_prompt.py) as a base class since it was made for that purpose.

Besides sending separate activities, another alternative to sending the text and the audio in the same activity would be to send just the audio and have the bot convert the audio into text using [Cognitive Speech Services](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/cognitive-services/speech-services/). This probably wouldn't be ideal because then your client wouldn't be able to display the text since it's not doing the conversion on its end. I'm assuming you are having the having the user provide audio input with the microphone and then converting it into text rather than having the user enter text and then converting it into audio.

[Direct Line Speech](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/speech-service/direct-line-speech) is a [builtin way](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/directline-speech-bot) of leveraging Cognitive Speech Services so that both your client and bot can access the text. And depending on your needs, you might consider looking into [Web Chat speech](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-WebChat/tree/master/samples/03.speech).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed description. Is uploading attachment about uploading it directly to channel's blob storage or Uploading the content to any other cloud storage and sharing the URL of hosted file. I could not find much details about uploading attachment other than [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/rest-api/bot-framework-rest-connector-api-reference?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#attachment-operations) and [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-howto-v4-storage?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=python#memory-storage)

Comment: It means uploading it anywhere you want. Azure, Dropbox, OneDrive, your own personal server, wherever. If you need help understanding how your app can upload a file then you should ask a new question about it because that's not bot-related. I should mention that I don't think uploading is the direction you actually want to go because that will be much slower than streaming and may introduce other issues.

Comment: We might look into using Direct Line speech in our next phase. As of now, uploading file to a storage seems the only way out. In general, if a user has to send a file to bot from a custom client, is uploading file to some storage the only way?

Comment: In general, no. You have a custom client so you can do anything you want with it. You can ignore the Bot Framework completely and set up your own schemas for exchanging data between your client and the bot. You can set up two-way real-time communication using WebSockets. The possibilities are endless. The point I was making is that Bot Framework activities should be kept small and it's better for their attachments to use a remote URL instead of embedded data.